# Display related has_many data inside once cell in Yii TbExtendedGridView

Tags: yii

What i have:
1 'user' table (id, username) with 'user' model
1 'date' table (id, user_id, date) with 'date' model
Each user can have one or more dates.

I have view with TbExtendedGridView (bootstrap CGridView) widget that needs to show list of users (each user 1 row) and users dates.

I have set up relations inside model and in database.

When i try to display dates for each user by simply telling view to show data from date relation, it throws and error that array needs to be string. I understand that, as one user has many dates, it will give those dates in array.

What i did next is i created function inside date column's 'value' which uses foreach loop and echoes all dates.

My question is, how do i move that function out of the view to model, and to which model do i move it? Leaving it inside view just feels simply wrong.

I'd appreciate suggestion how to deal with this. I need every user in 1 row. One cell username, one cell dates for that username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestion is to move it to the user model and name it for example getDatesDetails() that should return whatever string you need and in your column you can user 'value'=>'$data->getDatesDetails()' or 'value'=>'datesDetails'

Comment: Moved it to user model, and accessing it by using: 'value'=>'$data->getDatesDetails()'