# Yii, filtering and ordering column in grid view that has data from custom model function

Tags: yii

This is follow up on this question:

[Display related has_many data inside once cell in Yii TbExtendedGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787059/display-related-has-many-data-inside-once-cell-in-yii-tbextendedgridview)

I got that cell working, but now i have no idea how to make it sortable and filterable (filter field is hidden).

View:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'user_name',
        'favorite_color',
        array(
            'value'=>'$data->getAllDates()',
        ),
    ),
));
```

One user can have many Dates that can be single date or date range, so i have getAllDates function that fetches em all and put em all inside string so they can be represented inside single cell for that user.

Model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
    'listofdates' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Dates', 'user_id'),
    );
}

public function getAllDates()
{
    $data = '';


    foreach ($this->listofdates as $date) {
        $data .= $date->start_date.'-'.$date->end_date;
    }
return $data;
}
```

I have no idea how to enable filtering and search for dates column. There is no even title for it or filter field.
I can enable filter field for that column by adding 'name' => 'whatever', but of course there is no single column in database for that data so i get MYSQL error.
I'm guessing i need to create another custom function for filtering but i have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an additional field for filtering and sorting $datesFilter and filter like this:

in model:

```
public $datesFilter;

public function rules()
{
    array(
        array('datesFilter', 'safe', 'on'=>'search')
    );
} 

public function search()
{
     $criteria=new CDbCriteria;  

     ...

     // filtering
     if ($this->datesFilter!==null)
        $criteria->addCondition('YOUR QUERY CONDITION');

     ...

     // sorting
     $sort = new CSort;
     $sort->attributes =
        array(
           ...
           'datesFilter'=>=>array('asc'=>'YOUR SORT ASC', 'desc'=>'YOUR SORT DESC'),
        );          
}
```

in view:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'user_name',
        'favorite_color',
        array(
            'value'=>'$data->getAllDates()',
            'name'=>'datesFilter',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: App is searching for datesFilter column, which doesnt exists. I have  no idea how to make this work. Is it ok for me to send you ftp / mysql data for test site i have with this so you can drop your eye on it? Maybe i missed something important while i copy pasted model / view code etc.

Comment: No need. Got it working by your example. Even changed it little bit, added date picked in filter etc. Thanks!